# Jamming Devices

Tags: interference

Im am thinking about building a low power broadband jamming device to blanket a small area, around 400 sq.ft. I want my frequency range to be from DC to 100 ghz. Would amplifying the outputs of noise diodes that are summed to produce this broad a frequency range be the cheapest way to build this device? ( please don't mention in your answers that jamming devices are illegal: I know and I don't care. This is for scientific research only). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It probably is the cheapest way looking at how others have done it - as far as you must be "truly" broad in the interference.

- Maxim has a [application note](http://www.maxim-ic.com/app-notes/index.mvp/id/3469) on how to build a white noise generator. Apart from your range demands this seams like a nice way to do it.
- Googleling gives a few more [examples](http://bytecollector.com/archive/misc/BuildYourOwnNoiseSource.pdf) etc. However most are not not meant to be broadcasting.

And some not so wide examples (that are meant to be broadcasting):

- Adafruit have [blueprints](http://www.ladyada.net/make/wavebubble/) for a jammer (that is not as wide as you wish) (but no kit for sale)
- iinstructables have more than [one](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Create-Your-Signal-Jammer/) [jammers](http://www.instructables.com/tag/?sort=none&limit%3atype%3aid=on&q=jammer) (but they are mostly narrow)

Not a good answer to your question, sorry but I hope it can help you.

Comment: Np, and like you say I don't know what you are doing so I simply assumed you have the proper permits if you go and do something like this.